# Where Clause in orchard cms Query Filter

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

i am building a module where i need to add filter to my custom content type based on where clause. do i need to create a filter class in module or i can add it using Orchard admin options.

Answer (score 0):

If with where clause you meant the linq Where expression, yes. You need to create your own CustomFilter. Sipke describes how to do it here: http://www.ideliverable.com/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-5

Comment: I believe this content has moved here: http://www.ideliverable.com/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-5

Comment: You're right. I just updated the link. Thanks for pointing it out